# CentoOS 6.5 OS missing ifcfg-eth0 and cannot connect to the Internet

Tags: linux, networking

I setup CentOS 6.5 as a second OS on my laptop.

After my installation, I tried to connect to the Internet, and determined my OS only sees the `lo` interface. When I run `ifconfig -a` 
to find all the interfaces the OS sees, it only finds `lo`.

There is no file name as `ifcfg-eth0` in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` directory.

And there is no file name as `70-persistent-net.rules` in the `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory.

When I as a root user to execute `ifup eth0` command, the response is

> Device eth0 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just create the `ifcfg-eth0` as `sudo` and then `echo` in your applicable detail for the network configurations, and then run `systemctl restart network` and see if that resolves the problem.

> **Note:** *Be sure to change the values of the applicable fields depending on what configurations you need in your environment when you
>   create the [interface configuration
>   file](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces)
>   manually.*

1. **Commands (create static IP assigned config)**

   ```
   echo "DEVICE=eth0
   BOOTPROTO=static
   ONBOOT=yes
   IPADDR=192.168.0.199
   NETMASK=255.255.255.0
   GATEWAY=192.168.0.1" >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
   systemctl restart network
   ```
2. **Commands (create DHCP assigned IP config)**

   ```
   echo "DEVICE=eth0
   BOOTPROTO=dhcp
   ONBOOT=yes" >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
   ```

> ***Furthermore, consider rebooting the CentOS*** after making the needed changes with the correlated IP settings for your environment.

### Supporting Resources

- [Interface Configuration File](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces)
- [CentOS ifcfg-eth0 config file deleted. Utility to recreate it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/272968/centos-ifcfg-eth0-config-file-deleted-utility-to-recreate-it)

Comment: @cwcing ... Obviously use either `#1` or `#2` as per this answer I provided so whichever you need depends on your environment and correlated configuration needs.